# Properly categorize dom content into Array with XPath

Tags: php, xpath

Example HTML:

```
<div class"classX">
<a href="#" class="aClass">Link Text 1</a>
<span class="sClass"><p>Text #1</p></span>
</div>

<div class="classX">
<a href="#" class="aClass">Link Text 2</a>
</div>

<div class="classX">
<a href="#" class="aClass">Link Text 3</a>
</div>

<div class="classX">
<a href="#" class="aClass">Link Text 4</a>
<span class="sClass"><p>Text #4</p></span>
</div>

<div class="classX">
<a href="#" class="aClass">Link Text 5</a>
<span class="sClass"><p>Text #5</p></span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to build an array that will look like:

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 1
            [span_text] => Text #1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 4
            [span_text] => Text #4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 5
            [span_text] => Text #5
        )
```

But using a `foreach` loop with a `$key` value organizes the output incorrectly and instead, I get an array that looks like this:

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 1
            [span_text] => Text #1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 2
            [span_text] => Text #4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 3
            [span_text] => Text #5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [link_text] => Link Text 5
        )
```

I fully understand why this happens, that's because I'm using `link_text` key when accessing the `span_text` value but I have no idea how to properly build an array with a correct combination.

PHP:

```
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$link_texts= $finder->query("//a[contains(@class, normalize-space('aClass'))]");
$span_text= $finder->query("//span[contains(@class,'sClass')]/@data-html");


foreach ($link_texts as $key => $link_text) {

    if (empty($span_text[$key]->textContent)) {
        $link_text = trim($link_text->textContent);
        $dataArr[] = str_replace("\n", " ", $link_text);
        $data[] = array("link_text"=>str_replace("\n", " ", $link_text));
    } else {
        $span_text = str_replace("\n", " ", $span_text[$key]->textContent);
        $span_text = preg_replace('~</?p[^>]*>~', '', $span_text);
        $link_text = trim($link_text->textContent);
        $data[] = array("link_text"=>str_replace("\n", " ", $link_text), "span_text"=>$span_text);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to start by selecting all the parent `<div class"classX">` elements. Then we can select the nested `a` and `span` elements for each `div`.

```
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$divs = $finder->query("//div[@class='classX']");
$data = array();

foreach($divs as $div) {
    $link = $finder->query("./a[@class='aClass']", $div)->item(0);
    $span = $finder->query("./span[@class='sClass']", $div)->item(0);
    $items = array(
        "link_text" => $link ? $link->textContent : null, 
        "span_text" => $span ? $span->textContent : null
    );
    $data[] = array_filter($items);
}

print_r($data);
```

This produces a `$data` array with all the `link_text` and `span_text` items in the correct order.

Null values are removed by `array_filter`, so some nested arrays don't have a `span_text` key.
If a constant number of items is required, then don't flter the `$items` array.

Comment: That's a great idea. Is there a way to avoid `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` errors when running `$finder->query("./span[@class='sClass']", $div)->item(0)->textContent`? Maybe with an `if` statement that checks if this query returns NULL?

Comment: Nevermind, I have found what I needed by doing this: `if (!empty($finder->query("./span[@class='sClass']", $div)->item(0)->textContent))`. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the code with a check for NULL items, so PHP won't throw any warnings.